# In EJB module jndi-lookup doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, ejb, jndi

My project structure

```
app
   - web
   - service
   - dao
   - scheduler
```

I use spring framework. My modules: web is war, service and dao jar, scheduler is ejb. I want to use jndi-lookup in both my modules web and scheduler.

My WEB-INF/web.xml contains

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DataSource Reference</description> 
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> 
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

My web module context contains

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/DS" />
```

My scheduler ejb module contains

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/DS" />
```

On my app server i do mapping jdbc/DS to jdbc/DS-1.1 (version)

Web module works fine, but in scheduler dataSource doesn't initiate. Also works right then i use @Resourse("jdbc/DS") instead `<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/DS" />`

Comment: I think you are configuring the datasource in the Spring container. not to the EJB container in the server. so, EJB will not be able to look into the Spring container to get the JNDI resource. May be i am talking wrong.. Just a thought..

Comment: If i rename resource to original name (without version), then it will work. My problem is that in ejb module spring lookup bypassing mapping